# Good practice to "Clear Caches" before you "Backup Database"?

Tags: database, cache

Every time I create a database backup, I find myself instinctively clearing the cache first. My gut tells me that any cached data would be unnecessarily included in the export.

**Is this helpful, or am I just being OCD?**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this helpful, or am I just being OCD?

Completely OCD. :)

The database backup class already excludes unnecessary tables like asset indexing data, sessions, template caches, etc. during a backup.

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/master-v2/src/etc/db/DbBackup.php#L46

Comment: Boom... and I see all three `templatecache` tables listed there. Didn't even think about assets or sessions!